# Exception questions Java

Tags: java, exception

For example if I was making an image API in Java would it be more beneficial to have multiple exception classes such as ImageSizeException, ImageFormatException or have a single exception class such as ImageException which has a string, enum ect for what kind of exception it is.

As a secondary question if you use multiple exception classes would it be more acceptable to group them in an exceptions package or with the classes that would throw them

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107848/exception-handling-and-interfaces-in-java/20107896#20107896.  Is there information there that helps you?

Comment: The one time I created many exception classes for a Java application, I put them in their own package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should certainly have a base exception, ImageException, which is the superclass of any others.  Like Java has IOException.

Personally I would prefer one Exception with an Enum or int to subtype, but typical Java style is to have a lot of Exception subclasses.  Your should probably follow convention.

Answer (score 0):

It's Better to have many exceptions.it will be easier debugging when your code is huge,and you could have ImageException as the superclassfor all these exceptions.